Opensearch sercice Red status, Opensearch dashboads server is not ready yet, tried to connect through curl getting OpenSearch Security not initialized
Opensearch service cluster is showing red status and not able to connect to it to clear the shards.
I am getting "Opensearch dashboads server is not ready yet" when i try to access.
I get an message=>"Got response code '503' contacting OpenSearch at URL" in the logstash service.
i tried to connect from the same vpc through another linux machine with below command and getting "OpenSearch Security not initialized."
curl -XGET  -u oss-user:xxxxxx 'https://vxxxxxxx:443/_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason'

curl -XPUT -u oss-user:xxxxxx 'https://vxxxxxxx:/index-2024.05.27/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
  }
}'

Finally i am not able to connect to the cluster to remove shards and manage settings or to delete the index.
are there any other options to connect and resolve the red status issue in AWS Openserch service?
